# Transaction Replication from Read Only Secondary of AlwaysOn Availability Group

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know if its is possible to perform transactional replication as a publisher from a read only secondary of an AlwaysOn Availability Group?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Replication makes writes into the publisher for metadata (e.g. syspublications, sysarticls, etc), which is disallowed at a secondary in an AG.